# Ordering navigation in pico

Tags: php, twig

I am using Pico from dev7studios for my project. It is a static site generator using Markdown formatting and twig templating engine. I am using a plugin called Navigation from pico to get the dynamic links of the pages. The problem is that pico generates an alphabetically sorted navigation list. What I want is to order the navigation based on my needs.
For example:
Home
About Us
Contact Us

instead of:
About Us
Contact Us
Home

Any suggestion please..

Comment: i dont think your pico is the same as the tag or what i know as pico wich is just a text editor?

Comment: @Dagon Perhaps you can make a "pico-cms" tag? :)

Comment: Are any of these answers correct? Try mark one of them as the solution. This helps others later when having the same problem, like me.

Answer (score 3):

While the file naming solution should work, there is a plugin that enables you to set an order via a custom meta tag on each file:

https://github.com/ollierik/Pico-Placing

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [Pico](http://pico.dev7studios.com/) supports only 'alpha' and 'date' ordering. How about naming the .md files so that the pages they represent are sorted correctly when using 'alpha' (the default)?

Example:

```
content/10-home.md    => Home
content/20-about.md   => About Us
content/30-contact.md => Contact Us
```

You could name them 01, 02 and 03 too, but if you leave some open numbers, it may be easier to insert new menu items where you want, later.

Comment: Hi. It works, but you get urls like :
website.com/10-category/30-mypage